# Report error in Step:Add the Push Notifications feature to your App ID

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

In [developer website](https://developer.apple.com) , I make my `app ID`'s `Push Notifications` enable.

But in my project,`TARGETS` -> `Capabilities` -> `Push Notifications` -> I want to open it, but after sometime, there report `error` in

> Step:Add the Push Notifications feature to your App ID

The picture I token:

[image: tHE]

Additional info is: I use `Xcode 8`, `iOS 10`

---

**Edit -1**

In my `Signing`, there is error:

[image]

---

**Attempt - 1**

I have restart my `Xcode 8` , and it does not work for me.

Comment: Is your project bundle connected with any team (Developer account)?

Comment: @EI Captain It is connected in my `company Team`

Comment: @aircraft can you check your account in preferences which error is comming ?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: @William Grand, I finally solved this issue, as if I re-generate the  development `provisioning profile` and Adhoc `provisioning profile`, (make sure the app ID is enabled push notification)and in the target Signing I set the signing manually. I am sorry about the uncertain comment, if you test this is correct, please reply.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred to me when moving from XCode 7 to XCode 8.
To resolve this, I had to disable Push Notifications and re-enable them. Then I had to make sure that in Build Settings the Code Signing Identity and the Provisioning Profile were configured correctly with the account and provisioning profile associted to the AppID that have de Push Notifications enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you  enabled push notification in app ID but you didn't create provisioning profile for this app ID  so Xcode select provisioning profile automatically and that provisioning  file not support push notification capability , so try to create provisioning profile for this app ID and download it then double click on it to listen in Xcode try to restart Xcode , hope this help you .

Comment: I also think maybe this reason, but now, I can not login `developer.apple.com`, the network is unstabitily, I am in China, so now I can not test